# Lisp order of operations in lambda for mapcar

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am running `clisp` in Linux, and playing with the exercises in the book, *ANSI Common Lisp*. One of them says to use `mapcar` to create a function which takes a list of integers and returns a list in which each element is the original element plus its index in the list. So if I execute `(foo '(0 0 0))` it would produce `(0 1 2)`, etc.

What I tried is this:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((c 0))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (+ x c) (incf c)) lst)))
```

What I get when I run `(foo '(0 0 0))` is `(1 2 3)`. Just as an experiment, I swapped the  order of the increment around and defined it this way:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((c 0))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (incf c) (+ x c)) lst)))
```

and I got exactly the same results (in this case, I would expect `(1 2 3)`, but not in the former case). I also tried wrapping the sequence like this `(progn (+ x c) (incf c))` and got the same result. To make the function work, I need to do `(let ((c -1)))`. Why does the order of `(incf c)` and `(+ x c)` not seem to matter in this context? It would appear that `(incf c)` is always done first regardless, but I am not sure why. I know I'm missing something fundamental here, so this should be a quick and easy answer from a LISP pro to explain to me why this works this way. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a dummy. :-/ Kudos to those who answered and helped me see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, the result of the lambda function is the result of the last form, `(incf c)`. `(+ x c)` is ignored.

In your second example, you first increment c, so 1 is added to the first number, 2 to the second, etc.

For your first example, you could also use `prog1` to return the value of the *first* form, not the last:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((c 0))
    (mapcar
     (lambda (e) (prog1 (+ e c) (incf c)))
     lst)))
```

Comment: Oh geez I knew it was something stupid. Thanks. BTW, could you explain your alternative? I thought the proper syntax of passing a `lambda` to `mapcar` necessitated `#'(lambda...`. I'm still learning.

Comment: @Vatine yes, thanks. Again it was a brain fart on my part. I see that clearly now.

Comment: Thanks again uselpa, I understand your use of `prog1` now that I've examined it a bit more.

Comment: I think an even simpler solution, though, would be to use `(+ e (incf c))` and just start `c` at `-1` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: this is aimed at exploring some of the ways to make this happen.  You noted in your question some of these solutions (e.g., starting at -1), and I don't mean by including them here to suggest that you hadn't considered them.  This answer is more about considering the role of a pre- and post-increment operators in value-oriented languages.*

Note that `(incf c)` not only performs a side effect (where order would matter), but also returns the new value of `c`.  That is, `incf` is a pre-increment operator.  That means that it's absolutely acceptable to write `(+ x (incf c))`, as in:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((c 0))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                (+ x (incf c)))
            lst)))

(foo '(0 0 0))
;=> (1 2 3)
```

Now, those results aren't terrible, but they don't add the indices of the elements to the elements, because indices start at zero, not one.  You could do a simple change and add the subtraction:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((c 0))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                (+ x (1- (incf c)))) ; or (+ x -1 (incf c)), etc.
            lst)))

(foo '(0 0 0))
;=> (0 1 2)
```

Even better than this, in my opinion, would be to use the first form, and just start `c` at `-1`.  It's what I'd probably *do*, anyhow, and you noted in your question that this is an option:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((c -1))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                (+ x (incf c)))
            lst)))

(foo '(0 0 0))
;=> (0 1 2)
```

We might ask, though, whether there's a way to approximate a post-increment operator so that we didn't have to see (in our code) the subtraction?  That is, we might view the above as what we have in some languages:

```
result.add( x + ++c )
```

and ask why we can't just do

```
result.add( x + c++ )
```

instead?  This is simple enough:

```
(defmacro post-incf (place)
  `(1- (incf ,place)))

(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((c 0))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                (+ x (post-incf c)))
            lst)))

(foo '(0 0 0))
;=> (0 1 2)
```

Actually, there's no flexibility in C-like language's pre- and post-increment operators, but [`incf` and `decf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_incf_.htm) in Common Lisp afford a little bit more through the use of optional arguments, wherein a second, optional argument, can be used to specify by *how much* the value should change.  It's not too hard to adjust `post-incf` to handle such a second argument.  A first attempt might be:

```
(defmacro post-incf (place &optional (delta-form 1))
  `(- (incf ,place ,delta-form) ,delta-form))
```

That will work just fine for constant values such as `1`, but it will evaluate the `delta-form` multiple times, and we don't want that (since it could have side effects, or be expensive to compute).  We just need to be a little more careful to evaluate it only once, and thus:

```
(defmacro post-incf (place &optional (delta-form 1))
  (let ((delta (gensym (symbol-name '#:delta-))))
    `(let ((,delta ,delta-form))
       (- (incf ,place ,delta) ,delta))))

(let ((a 0))
  (list a                ; => 0
        (incf a 3)       ; => 3
        (post-incf a 2)  ; => 3 (but x is now 5)
        a))              ; => 5
;=> (0 3 3 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, Joshua, that's very helpful.

Comment: Although seeing as how `incf` and `decf` bot take an optional increment value (defaulting to 1), I would have preferred having that option in `post-incf` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your first lambda, `(lambda (x) (+ x c) (incf c))`, you are performing one side-effect-free addition and throwing away its value. Then you increment `c` and return, as the value from the lambda, its new value.

Try calling `(foo '(10 10 10))` and see what the return value is, the two versions will return `(1 2 3)` and `(11 12 13)`.

Comment: Yes, thanks (+1). A big "duh" on my part. That's very clear. I feel like a dork now before all the SO LISP pros... :p